# What object are Javascript global variables stored in?

Tags: javascript, object, global-variables

Are global variables stored in specific object? For instance:

```
var test="stuff";
console.log(window.test);
console.log(document.test);
console.log(this.test);
```

All three of these tests result in `undefined`, so is there an object that holds these variables?

I feel as though this is something stupid that I should already know, but I can't even seem to find the answer online.

Comment: Short answer: how you refer to the global variable depends on your environment.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "environment"? The browser, scope, OS?

Comment: JavaScript can run in browsers, in Adobe Photoshop, in old VRML browsers, within engines you can embed in Java programs and many other  host systems.  We call these the "host environments."  So yes, it could be a browser.  JavaScript programs manipulate objects from these environments.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think you'll find on most browsers, they *are* stored in `window`.

Far-fetched psychic debugging attempt: did you test this in jsFiddle? Or perhaps in Firebug? If so, you're probably seeing `undefined` for all three because in that case <strike>the code is executed in a frame; so it has a different `window` object (I think)</strike> the code is actually wrapped:

```
window.addEvent('load', function() {
  var test="stuff";
  console.log(window.test);
  console.log(document.test);
  console.log(this.test);
});
```

You can see from the above snippet from jsFiddle that `test` is *not* a global variable, which explains why it hasn't been attached to `window`.

I'm no expert, but this answer appears to be accurate from what I can tell in Chrome, Firefox, Safari, and Opera. To verify, I created an HTML file with the following content and loaded it in each browser:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var test = "stuff";
  alert(window.test);
</script>
```

Sure enough, "stuff" every time.

Comment: I knew there was a reason I thought "this is something stupid that I should already know". You're exactly right, I was using jsFiddle... Thanks for pointing me in the direction of my own stupidity. haha

Comment: I'm with Ray; it's definitely a good question. In fact it's kind of bizarre the more I think about it that this answer is actually true.

Comment: +1 for digging into the jsfiddle internals.  Nice answer.  The wrapping, however, actually _isn't_ bizarre; IMHO it is a clever way to run JavaScript from a JavaScript environment without (directly?) using `eval`. :)

Comment: @RayToal: Oh, I didn't mean the *wrapping* was bizarre. I was referring to the fact that in JS declaring a variable with `var` at the global scope is actually attaching it to an object (e.g., `window` in browsers, `global` in Node) whereas within a local scope it isn't.

Comment: Ah yes, that _is_ bizarre! One would expect top-level variables (defined with `var`) to be variables in a stack frame, as opposed to directly being added as properties to an object.

Comment: Another thing that might be worth mentioning is that if you declare your variable with `let` or `const` instead of `var` in the above example, `undefined` will be displayed and not `stuff`. Indeed, “At the top level of programs and functions, `let`, unlike `var`, does not create a property on the global object.” [MDN — let, JavaScript reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let)

Answer (score 23):

Here is a late but technical answer.

You ask

> Are global variables stored in specific object?

The answer is yes; they are stored in something called, officially, *the global object*.  This object is described in Section 15.1 of the [official ECMAScript 5 Specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf).

The global object is not required to have a name; but you can refer to its properties, such as `String`, `isNaN`, and `Date` simply by using their name.  Your JavaScript host environment will place other properties in the global object besides the ones required by the ECMAScript specification, such as `alert` or `console`.  In a browser, I can write the script

```
alert("Hello world");
```

because `alert` is a property of the global object.

Note that there does not have to be a way to access this global object at all, believe it or not.  The cool thing, however, is that many host environments will put a property in the global object whose value *is a reference to the global object itself*.  In most web browsers, this property is called `window`.  So we can write:

```
alert("Hello");
window.alert("Hello");
window.window.alert("Hello");
window.window.window.window.window.alert("Hello");
```

and you can also say:

```
var x = 5;
alert(this.x);
```

and get `5` alerted.

Answer (score 5):

A "true" global variable don't have the "var" keyword.
Try this:

```
test="stuff";
console.log(window.test);
console.log(document.test);
console.log(this.test);
```

With this, all scopes will see it. Variables with the var keyword are local to the scope that they were declared.

A variable will be "global to window" (property of window object) only if you declare it in the window scope as Dan said, making it global to the browsers that usually use window as the global scope.

Comment: A "true" global? If you use `var` in the global scope it makes a global variable.

Comment: @nnnnnn The use of the double quotes was intentional ;)

Comment: Interesting. I tried this in jsfiddle, and I instead got "stuff", "undefined","stuff". And the first and last are the same because `this === window`. http://jsfiddle.net/5Xtaq/1/

Answer (score 2):

Global variables are stored in the global `window` variable. The following code works if you just declare it outside anything (like a function):

```
var test="stuff";
console.log(window.test);
```

similar proof is that `window.location.href` is the same as `location.href`

However, the problem may lie on where the variable was declared. For example, if you declared this variable in the function, it will only exist in the function, and not globally:

```
function foo(){

    //declaring inside function
    var test="stuff";

    //undefined, since the variable exists in the function only
    console.log(window.test);  

    //undefined, document refers to the document
    //which is the top DOM object, not the global window
    console.log(document.test); 

    //depends on what "this" refers to, especially 
    //when using call() or apply() to call the function
    //For normal function calls, usually it points to window as well
    console.log(this.test);  

    //none of the above refer to "test" that contains "stuff"
    //because you are looking in the wrong place   

}
```

Comment: It's the `var` keyword, [@davidbuzatto](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11573012/143295) had a good eye.