# Function scopes and global variables

Tags: javascript

```
var foo = '1',
    bar = '2';

console.log(foo, bar, window.foo); //1, 2, undefined

(function(foo){
    console.log(foo, bar); //2, 2
})(bar);
```

I have two trivial questions regarding the code above:

1. Why is `window.foo` undefined? Aren't all global variables attached to the window object by default?
2. Why is `foo ===`2 inside of the closure? I know that I'm passing the original `bar` with the alias `foo`, which is `2`, but outside of the function scope `foo` is still `1`. And as far as I know, the original `foo` can be accessed from inside of the closure as well. Is the "new foo" prioritized since it's passed as an argument to the IIFE?

http://jsfiddle.net/GbeDX/

Comment: Question 1 - look at how the fiddle is run - `onLoad`. Question 2 - you're right. The `foo` parameter "overwrites" the outer scope's `foo` but **only** inside of the IIFE. I think it's called shadowing. So you will no longer be able to reference the outer `foo` unless you change the parameter name...or if `foo` is actually set as a property of `window`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Why is `window.foo` undefined? Ins't all "global" variables automatically attached to the window object?

Yes, global variables become properties of `window`, but the code is not run in global scope in your fiddle. It is run in the `load` event handler (see the second checkbox on the left hand side, it says "onLoad"). Here it is run in global scope: http://jsfiddle.net/GbeDX/1/

> Why is `foo === 2` inside of the closure? [...]  And as far as I know, the original `foo` can be accessed from inside of the closure as well.

No, it can't. The *parameter* `foo` **shadows** the variable `foo`. If it is a global variable though, you can access it with `window.foo`.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes. My guess is you execute that code in some *debug* environment like Firebug, jsFiddle, etc., which implicitly wraps that code into a scope
2. You pass the value `2` into that self-executing anonymous function, and you access the value via the local argument `foo`. Since the *scope chain lookup* always works *bottom->up*, the resolving for that variable name stops at the local scope, where `foo` is found as argument.

Answer (score 1):

1. `window.foo === '1'`, unless you've run this inside of another function.
2. `foo === '2'` inside of the closure becuase you declared `foo` as an input argument to the function.  You could access the globally scoped `foo` if you hadn't decided to declare a locally scoped variable with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes. Probably you are seeing the variable `foo` as `undefined` because you are running your script in a debug environment like firebug or jsfiddle (related https://stackoverflow.com/a/11572991/975520)
2. No. The parameter `foo` overwrite the variable `foo`. But it's still a global variable, so you can use it as `window.foo`.